# Как разобрать строку, которая может быть нескольких типов?

Tags: preg_match, preg_replace

В общем, не получается разобрать строку, которая может быть нескольких типов:

```
friends$id 
friends$id_$mask
friends$id#$mode
friends$id_$mask#$mode
```

В слове friends иногда может быть и `_` типо `friends_cnt$id`.

`$id && $mask && $mode` - это числа.

Comment: С Вашего вопроса немного не понятна задача. Предоставьте тестовые данные. Что то вида

    func("friends$444$55555) => "444", "55555"

и тому подобное.

Comment: $key = "friends50";
$key = "friends50_1";
$key = "friends50#2";
$key = "friends50_1#2";
$key = "friend_cnt50";

Ключ может быть любым из выше перечисленных 
пробывал вот так:
preg_replace("/([a-z]+)([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)#([0-9]+)/ies","\$this->keys('\\1','\\2','\\3','\\4');", $key);

 но она определяет только ключ "friends50_1#2";
как сделать так чтоб оно любой из вышеперечисленных ключей разбирало и отправляло в функцию 
не обязательно preg_replace можно любой регуляркой лиж бы разбирало.

Comment: То, что Вы входные данные привели, это хорошо, а какие для них выходные должны быть? Не совсем понятно. В случае "friends50_1#2" понятно, массив friends,50,1,2. А в случае friend_cnt50 - что должно быть?

Comment: Так же, только friend_cnt,50  
Я эту строку показал только из-за того, что там есть нижнее подчеркивание, так как оно должно быть учтено в условии.